# lifetimes library - ISSUE of calculating CLV when using function: customer_lifetime_value of GammaGammaFitter

Tags: numpy-ufunc, lifetimes-python

I'm trying to calculate CLV(Customer Life Value) using `lifetimes` python library

so, I am fitting purchase behavior data on `ParetoNBDFitter` and fitting purchase price data on `GammaGammaFitter`.

and When I'm trying to calculate CLV based on `GammaGammaFitter.customer_lifetime_value()`, there are same errors about

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot apply ufunc <ufunc 'hyp2f1'> to mixed DataFrame and Series inputs.
```

Interestingly, I could calculate the CLV yesterday successfully, but today the above error is coming out. The code and data have not been modified.

My code looped by date, each time I redefined the model and then calculated the CLV.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Workaround: use `numpy` instead of `series`. That is, do not use:

```
f.frequency
```

but

```
f.frequency.values
```